# how to get day name from queryset in django template?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I have a query set in Django template. It has a date time column. **I want to display only the day name . Is there any template filter which will help the cause?.**.....help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a Django `date` template filter:

```
{{ model.field|date:'l' }}
```

Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date).